# Google Chrome doesn't open in metro style

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, modern-ui

I have read that the dev build of Google Chrome can work in metro style in win 8 if it is the dev build, is the default browser, and is pinned to start. I did all that, and it is starting in desktop mode, even when I start it from the start menu. I am using version 24.0.1312.2 dev-m or Google Chrome and Windows 8 Pro. What can I do to make Chrome open as a Metro App?

Comment: Current stable version of Chrome has a Metro version, upon installation you'll be prompted if you want it to be your default browser; agreeing to that will allow you to use its Metro interface.

Comment: Are you sure it is set to default? Check out other browser's as well for default.

Comment: I do not use Chrome, but I noticed that there is a Chrome app available in the windows store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Chrome's set to default and still doesn't launch in Metro mode, despite opening it from the Start Screen then you'll have to instruct Chrome to open in Windows 8 Mode.

To do this, Click on the Chrome menu and select "Relaunch in Windows 8 Mode"

[image]

Comment: Works! I would like there to be a way to make it start in Windows 8 mode in the first place without having to do this, but it is still okay.

Comment: Never mind. If you do this once it automatically opens in metro until you change it again.